# How to join dimension tables while populating a fact table if business key of one dimension table is not in the other joining table?

Tags: primary-key, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have an OLTP database having some tables. I want to build a DW star schema from this database. I extracted three tables--Customer, Store, SalesPerson--from source to staging area and put a surrogate key as primary key in all three tables. These three tables also have respective primary keys (business keys) from OLTP but don't have relationship with each other through foreign keys. After that I populated dimension tables from staging area. Now i want to populate fact table from these dimension tables. The strategy is that I have to join dimension tables based on their business keys and put surrogate key of each dimension to fact table along with some fact values. But the problem is that the dimensions don't have business keys on which I could join them. And if I join dimensions on surrogate keys then how to keep track to the OLTP in case of SCD type 2?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjMLP.png)

The image is attached. This is the source OLTP. I want Customers, Products, Offices and Employees as dimension tables and "Price each","quantity ordered" as facts. Can you please how can I build a data warehouse from these mentioned tables and fact. Thank you

Comment: Constraints, including PKs/UNIQUE & FKs, need not exist, be known or be declared to query. Table meanings (membership conditions) are necessary & sufficient. You seem to be talking about a table with dimensions/columns Customer X Store X SalesPerson X data with Customer X Store X SalesPerson being a cross join of the associated tables. What is the problem? Where are you 1st stuck in what presentation of what design method? [mre] PS Tables represent relationships/associations. FK constraints are ubiquitously wrongly called "relationships", they are truths holding every situation/state.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually I stuck in how to populate fact table from these three dimension tables?

Comment: Hi - you don't populate a fact table from dimensions, you populate it from your source system. So you take your source fact record, using the columns in that record you look up the relevant dimension tables via the business keys to return the surrogate keys and then insert these surrogate keys into your fact record

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For look up the business key of one table must be a foreign key of the second table but in my case this is not. i mean the business key of one table is not foreign key on other table so on which key should i look up?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Your "the problem is that" is not clear. Exactly why/how is "the dimensions don't have business keys on which I could join them" a problem? Exactly where/how are you stuck accomplishing what having done what? [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] PS DDL gives ERD content.

Answer (score 0):

Say your source OLTP system has a sale record that looks like this:

| customer_id | product_id | sale_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | X1234 | 2022-07-26 | 13.67 |

In your data warehouse you have 3 dimension tables:

Customer_dim:

| customer_sk | customer_bk |
| --- | --- |
| 9876 | ABCD |

Product_dim:

| product_sk | product_bk |
| --- | --- |
| 5432 | X1234 |

Date_dim:

| date_sk | date_bk |
| --- | --- |
| 20220726 | 2022-07-26 |

From your source record, you take each relevant column, join it to the BK in the relevant dimension table to look up the corresponding SK and then write the record to your fact table. So your fact table would look like this:

| customer_sk | product_sk | date_sk | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9876 | 5432 | 20220726 | 13.67 |

Comment: I'd hoped that the example in my answer would explain how you do this but I'm guessing it hasn't. I'm not sure why you keep talking about foreign keys as they are totally irrelevant to the problem and its solution. What is it about my answer that you don't understand or don't think addresses your question?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer my question.  As you mentioned above "take each relevant column, join it to the BK in the relevant dimension table to look up the corresponding SK and then write the record to your fact table" . The question is that business keys of each dimension has different values some are integers some are alphanumeric so how can i join dimensions on business keys. As i know while joining query will look for matched keys but in this case keys are not matched. I have edited my post and put an image of OLTP source. Hope you got my point

Comment: The customer table has business keys like " 112,114,119", the product table has business keys like "S10_1678, S10_1949, S10_2016" , the employee table has business keys like "1002, 1056, 1076" and the office table has business keys like " 1, 2, 3, 4". so how can i join tables on these business keys as they all are different and will not match while joining. Thank you and i hope now i cleared my problem statement.

Comment: The corresponding dimension tables for each of these source tables also hold the relevant business keys. You join the business keys in your source fact records to the business keys in your dimension tables to get the surrogate keys and write this all to your fact record. You seem to think you need to join business keys between unrelated tables - that’s not what my answer says and i’m not sure why you think this?

Comment: Yes because my desired dimension tables are unrelated tables mean they don't share business keys with each other but I have to join them. so there is any solution for this particular problem when source tables are unrelated and don't share business keys?? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm going to have to give up. You keep just repeating yourself and never comment on, or appear to have even read, anything I've said